# Cordova IOS App crashes immediately after launch in Testflight

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcode9, testflight

I have been using TestFlight for several months now to distribute new builds to our beta testers and for the most part I haven't had any problems. Now the app is crashing immediately after launch and I have no idea what the problem is.

The app runs fine in the simulator, and runs fine on our test devices if installed directly. These crashes are only occurring installing the app through TestFlight. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can track this problem.

IOS App is built using cordova.